# Looking for data in a binary tree that isn't built around the data type you're looking for

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a binary tree with the data of each node being based off people (first and last name, zip code, ssn, and birthdate). That tree was based around the first and last name of those people when created (comparing strings, with the smaller going to the left), but I need to find the oldest person in that same binary tree. My current code is below, and I think I'm on the right path logically. Right now it's just returning an error with rightold and leftold not being NULL, but what should their initial value be? Is there a flaw in my logic how it stands now? I'm really stumped right now and have been tweaking it for a while. Thanks in advance!!

PS - The date value is the combination of YYYYMMDD as an int, which is why I want the smallest date value to be my oldest in the comparisons.

```
node * Tree::oldest(node * x)
{ 
   node * rightold, * leftold, * res, * finalRes; 
   if (x -> right != NULL)
   {
      rightold = oldest (x->right); 
   }
   else if (x -> left != NULL)
   {
       leftold = oldest (x->left);
   }
   if (rightold -> date < leftold -> date)
        res = rightold;
   else
       res = leftold;
   if (res -> date < x -> date)
       finalRes = res;
   else
       finalRes = x;
   return finalRes; 
}
```

Comment: You don't check `x`, `rightold`, or `leftold` before dereferencing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to check both children, not just one or the other; since the tree isn't sorted by age, the oldest person in the tree could be in either sub-branch.

So instead of:

```
node * rightold, * leftold, * res, * finalRes; 
if (x -> right != NULL)
{
   rightold = oldest (x->right); 
}
else if (x -> left != NULL)
{
    leftold = oldest (x->left);
}
```

try:

```
node * rightold = NULL, * leftold = NULL, * res = NULL, * finalRes = NULL; 
if (x->right) rightold = oldest (x->right); 
if (x->left)   leftold = oldest (x->left);
```

Also, your code that compares `leftold` and `rightold` to see which is older needs to handle the case where one or both of those two pointers is NULL, otherwise it will crash when it tries to derefence a NULL pointer.